# quickstart Apache DayTrader

Tags: postgresql, openshift, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to get the Apache DayTrader benchmarking app on OpenShift quickstart working see link https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_type/quickstart!17609

I have a free 3 gear openshift online account and the quickstart starts up but then after a while posts the message 
"Application creation is taking longer than expected. Please wait a few minutes, then refresh this page."
Waiting and refreshing the page shows the whole application rolled back and removed from the gear.
I suspected it might need a larger gear but I can build an openshift gear manually with JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 and PostgreSQL 9.2 as per requirements in a small gear
I tried manually building the application via jboss developer studio and downloaded the git locally, imported it as a general project,converted to Mavern project, started openshift application wizard and choose the jbosseap-6 app type with postgresql-9.2 cartridge and went through using the existing daytrader project.

That all seemed to work and the app was created in my openshift online gear

Cartridges
JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6

Status: Started

Gears
1 small, Storage 1 GB PostgreSQL 9.2

the account webpage then displays
"Welcome to your JBoss EAP application on OpenShift"
but I cant seem to access the daytrader index.jsp or app from there.

If anyone has successfully built Daytrader on openshift either manually or via quickstart could they please post the steps. 
I am just starting with jboss and the solution may be an absurdly simple oversight on my part.

Much appreciated John

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is not your cartridge.  If that is the case, you should try logging an issue on the github project that feeds into that quickstart here: https://github.com/gvijayar/daytrader

The creator of the cartridge should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I posted ( some time ago ) the issue in github for gvijayar but there has been no reponse. I have managed to build via command line as per "Deploying from Source" making allowance for the error.

The application name needs to change in the create command to be consistent across all the commands you list.
ex:

```
rhc app create -a daytradereap -t jbosseap-6 -g large
```

but the quickstart still fails consistently.